# Serve static html for homepage otherwise serve to index.php

Tags: apache, apache2.4

I've got a pretty standard rewrite rule to push everything through the index for my CMS to handle.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
  RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to serve my homepage and a couple cornerstone blogs as static html to improve load speeds. How do I tell Apache2 to serve `/path/to/some.html` when root is requested?

I've tried

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/$"
  RewriteRule ^/$ /path/to/some.html

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/some/important/path$"
  RewriteRule ^/$ /path/to/some/other.html

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
  RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But that's all still getting served through the index and being handled by the CMS. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is in .htaccess, so after each change is made, the processing will restart with the new path. The [END] flag was added to help short-circuit this kind of looping when a rule REALLY knows it wants to be final.

By contrast, the existing [L] flag only stops the current round of processing.

Comment: Its not in an .htaccess file its in the virtual host config file